# AccessViolationException в asp net web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Есть на сайте склады, кассы, движения. Всё это грузится просто замечательно. Но есть ещё и заказы. Я посмотрел в брейкпоинте, данные из бд берутся и после того как я в экшене возвращаю результат `return Content(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);` через полминуты где-то зажигается такое исключение
[image: Исключение]

Дальше что делать, ну не знаю просто

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вдруг у вас похожий сценарий, а именно тот случай когда вы берете данные из базы и благополучно возвращается и через какое-то время у вас появляется такой exception, проверьте проблемное место (в моём случае экшен с заказами) на наличие **self referencing loop**.
А именно вам следует использовать вспомогательные модели (ApiModels) в бизнес логике вместо моделей (Models), которые вы используете для хранения в базе.

Это как в MVC разделение моделей на ViewModels и Models. Т.к. у меня web api, то я назвал их ApiModels.
Если в ваших бд-моделях есть связи с другими моделями, то не используйте эти модели для выдачи в контроллерах. А лучше вообще никогда не используйте.